# How to start an app so that the user can send an email?

Tags: windows-store-apps

I'm porting a windows phone app and i have the following wp code:

```
public static void startEmailFeedbackActivity(Context context)
{
  EmailComposeTask emailcomposer = new EmailComposeTask();
  emailcomposer.To = Strings.IDST_FLAG_SUPPORT_EMAIL_ADDRESS;
  emailcomposer.Subject = Strings.IDST_EMAIL_FEEDBACK_TITLE;
  emailcomposer.Show();
}
```

QUESTION - How do I do this for my Windows Store App? Is It even possible?

I found some threads about this and i realize i should be using contracts, but it is not clear...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/winappswithcsharp/thread/393a123f-674c-4b44-af87-9963053f42fd

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!

```
public static async Task startEmailFeedbackActivity(Context context)
{
  string uriString;
  uriString = "mailto:?to=" + Strings.IDST_FLAG_SUPPORT_EMAIL_ADDRESS;
  uriString += "&subject=" + Strings.IDST_EMAIL_FEEDBACK_TITLE;
  uriString += "&subject=" + Strings.IDST_EMAIL_FEEDBACK_TITLE;

  Uri uri = new Uri(uriString);
  await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri); 
}
```